# Can I search for tracks in the Deezer catalog by BPM?

Tags: ios, deezer

I see from the API docs that Deezer tracks have a BPM attribute, is it possible to search for tracks filtering on the BPM attribute?

I wrote the [Tune Runner hack](https://www.hackerleague.org/hackathons/musichackday-bologna/hacks/tune-runner) at a recent Music Hack Day, and it matches up songs to the runner's pace. I'd love to use a single API provider, and perhaps Deezer can do search and streaming.

Answer (score 0):

For now you can't filter a Deezer API search on the BPM attribute. You still can do search on a specific genre and stream that filtering yourself on BPMs - good chance that if you pick Dance you'll have mostly fast pace for example.